# How to permanently redirect `http://` and `www.` URLs to `https://`?

Tags: google-app-engine, https, redirect

I have a Google App Engine project. On this project I have setup a custom domain and an SSL certificate. Therefore, I can use `https://www.mysite.xxx`, `http://www.mysite.xxx` and just the naked domain `mysite.xxx`.

Is it possible to permanently redirect the last two to always use the secure `https://` domain using the developers console or do I just have to redirect in the code?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So you can add `secure: always` to your yaml file

> **always**
>
> Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same
> path. Query parameters are preserved for the redirect. Example
>
> ```yaml
> - url: /youraccount/.*   
>    script: accounts.app   
>    login: required   
>    secure: always
> ```

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/config/appref?hl=en#handlers_secure)

Comment: I've read the documentation, but have had no luck. See below for my app.yaml. Do you see anything wrong with it?

runtime: nodejs
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: /public/index.js
  secure: always

Comment: For java - you can refer following URL - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work. According to this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/mVRvsySeef8 the redirect process should be done in your application, not in yaml.

Comment: The answer above is correct for AppEngine standard. On Flex you must take a different approach.

Answer (score 24):

(For Node at least,) in your app.yaml, add the following:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref

Answer (score 12):

For the sake of completeness. The Java way is to set the transport guarantee to confidential like this.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

You can also find this [here in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs).

Answer (score 6):

Just in case, it is not possible to include secure handlers in app.yaml on App Engine Flexible, there isn't support for them:

> The secure setting under handlers is now deprecated for the App Engine flexible environment. If you need SSL redirection, you can update your application code and use the X-Forwarded-Proto header to redirect http traffic. (Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#appyaml_changes)

The reference is from Java, but it seems to be the same for Node. I've tried to include handlers and it didn't work.

As you can see, a possible solution would be to "use X-Forwarded-Proto header to redirect http traffic". I haven't tried this because I will move to App Engine Standard, but someone has done it and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085977/7720472).

Answer (score 2):

In case your domain is purchased or [transferred](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9003139) to [Google Domain](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4639612?hl=id) then you could do it in [G-Suite](https://domains.google.com/registrar?hl=en) under the [Synthetic records](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069273?hl=en-US) section:

[image: screencapture-domains-google-redirect-registrar-chetabahana-com-dns-2019-05-27-21_19_24]

Answer (score 1):

It should be done in your application. Please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54289378/5293578

I've tried the following code and it worked for me (You must put this before the default request and error handler):

```
/**==== File: server.js =======**/

/** Express configuration **/

// HTTPS Redirection
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    var schema = (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || '').toLowerCase();
    if (schema === 'https') {
      next();
    } else {
      res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
  });
}

/** ... more configuration **/

// Default request handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // ... your code
});

// Default error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // ... your code
});
```

Comment: Only if you're un flexible environment, accepted answer is better for the standard env. Even on flexible things *might* change, see comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833147/4495081

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I added secure always on every handler in app.yml. My node server deployed on GCP serves angular for client-side and express API so in order for the angular route to work I had to add 'api' on API endpoints, so here is how it worked

```
runtime: nodejs14
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|JPG|css|js|ttf|map)(|\.map))$
  static_files: public/dist/\1
  upload: public/dist/(.*)(|\.map)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
- url: /api/.*  
  secure: always
  script: auto
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: public/dist/index.html
  upload: public/dist/index.html
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```